# Игнорирование переменной в url .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Нужно, чтобы при обращении на example/api/booking/{code} проводился редирект на index.php, который будет принимать code из ссылки в переменную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не ясно, почему вы это называете "игнорированием", но судя по описанию, решение будет следующим

```
RewriteRule ^example/api/booking/(.*) index.php?code=$1 [L,QSA}
```